# Facebook app integration to Fan Page Timeline

Tags: facebook

I have been trying to upload and app built in ruby to a facebook page I manage and keep getting "Sorry, something went wrong" and a 191 error.

I have optimized all of the settings and have been using this URL to add it to my fan page.

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL

app ID: 251045461667460

URLs:

https://www.electric-moon-2772.herokuapp.com/
https://apps.facebook.com/your_vision_hd/

I have also filled out all of the necessary details required. I cant figure out why this doesnt work.

Please HELP!

Thanks

Comment: Currently open bug report, the first one in the bug tracker: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/304168516342380?browse=search_4fcf95fa68e481454210650

Answer (score 0):

When I access: https://apps.facebook.com/your_vision_hd/ it says that https://www.electric-moon-2772.herokuapp.com/ is temporarily down or have moved... Also, your SSL Certificate is not valid, maybe that's the cause...

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response, Leo. I will work on what you have noted and see if that helps, thanks again!

Comment: Leo, i'm pretty sure it's the bug report i listed